# using susy compass plugin how do I add margin onto each of my elements correctly?

Tags: css, compass-sass, sass, susy-compass

I have 4 elements with widths set at `@include span-columns(3,12)` this outputs each element at 25% which is fine, what I would also like to do is add margin to each element but doing this breaks the layout of these elements as the 25% width and % margin get added together. Can anyone advise how I can combine the margin in with the width?

SCSS

```
    .m-info-col{

      .col{
        @include span-columns(3,12);
// tried this margin-right: columns(.5,12);

        &:last-child{
          @include omega;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have your container set up with 12 columns and have set $gutter-width to a value, then each column has $gutter-width gap (margin if you like).

If you implement susy grid backgrounds using:

```
$show-grid-backgrounds : true;
```

and inside your container context:

```
@include susy-grid-background;
```

You will see the gutters behind your design.

You can also add padding into the span-columns mixin (3rd param). This does not always work as expected though.

Another way I have used is the squish mixin and it adds columns as margins. This works quite well but I have not tried using 0.5 columns as the squish amount.

Comment: hey, i have set the gutter-width to be 0em as I require some of my elements to be tightly positioned to each other, is it possible to use $gutter-width in some sections and not on all?

Comment: Yes it can. You may need to do a `@include reset-columns;` after changing the value. And I would say you'd have to set it back after use.  But I have only done this with responsive design using `@include at-breakpoint() { $gutter-width:0em; @include reset-columns; @include susy-grid-background; }`.